# jquery on click select element if it's not in the specific class

Tags: jquery, select, click

I am trying to do this but no luck so far does anyone know how to select an element on click
but not include elements in specific div like `.box` and all content inside that `div .box`

small update:
thank you for responses, but if i am using `:not` or `hasClass` it won't assure that elements inside that `foo` won't be selected. like:

`<div class=foo>this won't be selected <span>this will</span></div>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    if (!(this).hasClass('foo')) {
        // the clicked element doesn't have the foo class        
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Works fine with this! if(!domEl.closest('div').hasClass('box'))

Comment: I just can't get it to work with jquery ui dialog, i guess that's because how the dialogs are built, having display:none, so i can't use && !domEl.closest('div').hasClass('ui-dialog')

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the :not() selector.

```
$("#mydiv:not(.box)").click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

if you have specific target elements, like you want to target `<li>` inside your specified container, then this should be ideal:

```
$("#mydiv:not(.box)>li").click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

This should only apply the click() function to the `<li>` child element of the container that's **not** got the `.box` class.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're looking for anchors, this should work...

```
$(":not(.box) a").click(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

However, I would suggest re-factoring your markup to make this easier.  For example, you could explicitly place a clickable / notclickable class on each element.